# Iterate through entire database, detect null or 0 values in Shape Area or Shape Length field and report them - ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select

I would like some code that goes through a database and reports any and all feature classes that have a 0 or a null value in an shape area or shape length attribute. If it could all get somehow put into one table with the table name to look at, that would be ideal.

For some reason my Python only runs on 5 random polygons in the database and ignores the rest of the polygon and line feature classes - dozens of them. This code will make a selection and put it in a file geodatabase, but it does so even if there are no results (if there are 0 results, I would like to have no output ideally). Why am I not getting the whole database and only 5 random fcs? And how can I get the type of output I'm looking for?

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = "Database Connections\\Production Server exa01 gis02p.sde"
output_workspace = "C:\\Users\\nam00009\\Desktop\\TempExport.gdb\\"

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')
datasets = [''] + datasets if datasets is not None else []

for ds in datasets:
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        
     # Describe a feature class using arcpy.Describe
     desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    if desc.shapeType == "Polygon":
      # Process: Select from Polygons 0 or null values from shape area or shape length
      arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, output_workspace + desc.baseName + "ZNCheck", "SHAPE.AREA = 0 OR SHAPE.LEN = 0 OR SHAPE.AREA IS NULL OR SHAPE.LEN IS NULL")
    
    elif desc.shapeType == "Line":
      # Process: Select from Lines 0 or null values from shape length
      arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, output_workspace + desc.baseName + "ZNCheck", "SHAPE.LEN = 0 OR SHAPE.LEN IS NULL")

    else:
    pass
```

Comment: Indentation is very important in python, your code is incorrectly indented, if this is a paste error correct it.

Comment: If you think there is an indentation error, please tell me what it is. If I knew what the problem was, then I wouldn't have posted this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "Database Connections\\Production Server exa01 gis02p.sde"

output_workspace = "C:\\Users\\nam00009\\Desktop\\TempExport.gdb"


def checkNULLGeom(fc):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(fc)
    arcpy.AddMessage(fc)
    oid_field = [fld.name for fld in arcpy.ListFields(fc) if fld.type=="OID"][0]
    null_geom = []

    ## get list of OIDs where NULL geom, area/length = 0
    if desc.shapeType == "Polygon":
        null_geom = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [oid_field, "SHAPE@", "SHAPE@LENGTH", "SHAPE@AREA"]) if row[1] == None or row[2] == 0 or row[3] == 0]

    ## get list of OIDs where NULL geom, length = 0
    elif desc.shapeType == "Polyline":
        null_geom = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, [oid_field, "SHAPE@", "SHAPE@LENGTH"]) if row[1] == None or row[2] == 0]

    ## if NULLS/0 found
    ## export to gdb
    if null_geom:
        arcpy.AddMessage("NULL GEOM FOUND")
        where_clause = "{0} IN ({1})".format(oid_field, ','.join([str(i) for i in null_geom]))
        arcpy.Select_analysis(fc, "{0}\\{1}".format(output_workspace, fc), where_clause)


################################################################################
## DATASETS

datasets = arcpy.ListDatasets(feature_type='feature')

for ds in datasets:
    arcpy.AddMessage(ds)
    for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(feature_dataset=ds):
        checkNULLGeom(fc)

################################################################################
## ROOT OF GEODATABASE

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    checkNULLGeom(fc)
```

Comment: Code result:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 44, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 11, in checkNULLGeom
IndexError: list index out of range

I think I manually deleted all the 0's and nulls. Is this why or does your code have another issue?

Comment: Line 11 is accessing the OID field, if you know what your OID field is you can replace the list comprehension here. For example oid_field = "OBJECTID". Strange it cant find an OID field though.

Comment: That fixed it, changing it to "OBJECTID" which is what ArcGIS uses. How could this be changed to produce a text file that lists off the table names where null / o geometry was found if positive and if none were found, to just print a statement on that text file to indicate that none were found? I added an else: print statement after the "if null_geom" line, but it outputs that for every feature class and it works if I'm running it manually and looking at it, but I'd like to run this as a scheduled task overnight and just check the file later. Thanks - I'm super new with Python.